# 70s or 80s horror movie, guy is cutting people up and throwing them in a portal to a monster?

Tags: story-identification

I saw this on Over The Air local television in the midwest in the mid to late 80s. It was either a 70s or 80s horror movie.

There are people disappearing. I've forgotten most of the movie except the ending.

The portal is in a cave. He's using a glowing rod to cut up the bodies. It doesn't harm him because he's 'chosen' by the monster on the other side of the portal. At the end of the movie it appears someone else is chosen because they get the rod from him, and use it to cut him up and throw him in.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That might be *[The Return](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheReturn1980)*.

[image: Cover image]

> *The Return* was made in 1980 and is a Science Fiction Horror Film featuring Raymond Burr, Martin Landau, Vincent Schiavelli, Jan-Michael Vincent, and Cybill Shepherd.
>
> Twenty five years after two children and a prospector see a UFO descend upon their sleepy New Mexico town, a series of cattle mutilations have occurred and all three find themselves being brought back together to discover what happens when the UFO returns.

The propector wielding the glowing rod:

Comment: This was the accepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93411/looking-for-a-sci-fi-film-from-the-80s-involving-cattle-mutilation/93414#93414